# DateTime field в моделях Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, orm

Доброго времени суток!

models.py

```
   week_day = models.ForeignKey(WeekDays)
```

Как-нибудь можно сделать выбор в этом поле именно по дню недели с помощью models.DateTimeField или models.DateField?
Суть в том чтобы выбрать день недели и поставить в других полях график работы для этого дня.

Comment: У вас дни недели хранятся в отдельной модели? 

Comment: пока не придумал как по другому сделать

Answer (score 0):

решил полем `weekday = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, default=1)`